# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Tenho uma query do qual ao executá-la, dá o seguinte erro:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted
>   to string

Confesso que nunca me deparei com esse erro. Todos os valores estão passando corretamente. O código que está dando esse erro segue abaixo:

```
mysqli_query(sprintf($this->conexao, "INSERT INTO cadastro_usuarios VALUES(null,0,'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','A',NOW());", 
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $nome),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $email),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $dataNascimento),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $endereco),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $telefone),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $celular),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $apelido),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $genero),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $filhos),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $site),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $facebook),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $instagram),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $twitter),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $nomeFoto),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $descricao)));
```

Comment: O objeto `$this->conexao` deve ser do tipo `string` para funcionar. O correto seria remove-lo.

Comment: Que descuido meu Valdeir. Na verdade ele tem que ficar fora do sprintf. Muito obrigado por me atentar a esse detalhe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O objeto `$this->conexao` deve ser do tipo `string` para funcionar. O correto seria remove-lo.

O correto (em seu código) provavelmente é:

```
mysqli_query($this->conexao, sprintf("INSERT INTO cadastro_usuarios VALUES(null,0,'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','A',NOW());", 
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $nome),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $email),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $dataNascimento),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $endereco),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $telefone),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $celular),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $apelido),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $genero),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $filhos),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $site),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $facebook),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $instagram),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $twitter),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $nomeFoto),
                mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $descricao)));
```

Comment: Perfeito Valdeir. Foi um descuido meu. Muito obrigado por me atentar a esse detalhe.